# How Do I Connect Oracle To PostgreSQL over ODBC using the Oracle ODBC Gateway?

Tags: linux, oracle, postgresql, odbc

I would like to select from a PostgreSQL instance on a server running openSUSE from an Oracle instance on a server running Oracle's custom Linux flavor.  I would like to do this using the Oracle ODBC gateway.  I have done this successfully in the past and continue to do it using the same Oracle box and other SUSE/Postgres boxes.

my ODBC manager on the SUSE (Postgres) side is: unixODBC

My odbc.ini is:

```
[postgresql]
Description         = Test to Postgres
Driver              = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Trace               = Yes
TraceFile           = sql.log
Database            = host
Servername          = localhost
UserName            = *****
Password            = *****
Port                = 5432
Protocol            =
ReadOnly            = Yes
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ShowOidColumn       = No
FakeOidIndex        = No
ConnSettings        =
```

My odbcinst.ini is

```
[postgresql]
    Description             = Postgresql driver for Linux
Driver          = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
UsageCount              = 1
```

my tnsnames.ora (with other ODBC entries omitted) is:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/11gR1/db/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dbs1)(PORT = 1522))

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dbs1)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

ODBC_SERVER123=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=dbs1)
      (PORT=1522)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
       (SID=server123)
    )
    (HS=OK)
  )
```

my listener.ora (with other SID_DESC entries omitted) is:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/11gR1/db/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
        (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
                (DESCRIPTION =
                        (ADDRESS_LIST=
                                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
                                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dbs1)(PORT = 1522))
                        )
                )
        )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /opt/oracle

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
        (SID_LIST=
                (SID_DESC=
                        (SID_NAME=server123)
                        (ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/11gR1/db)
                        (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
                        (ENVS=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/opt/oracle/product/11gR1/db/lib)
                )
        )

TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER = 0
LOGGING_LISTENER = off
```

Also, here is the inithost123.ora file located in $ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin:

```
#
# HS init parameters
#
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = server123
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 0
#HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=DEBUG
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libodbc.so

HS_FDS_SUPPORT_STATISTICS = FALSE

HS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
#HS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII
HS_FDS_TIMESTAMP_MAPPING = "TIMESTAMP(6)"
HS_FDS_FETCH_ROWS=1
HS_FDS_SQLLEN_INTERPRETATION=32

#
# ODBC specific environment variables
#
set ODBCINI=/etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini

#
# Environment variables required for the non-Oracle system
#
#set <envvar>=<value>
```

And just for good measure, my sqlnet.ora is:

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/11gR1/db/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

ADR_BASE = /opt/oracle
```

I added a gateway link oracle-side using the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK ODBC_SERVER123 CONNECT TO "*****" IDENTIFIED BY "*****" USING 'ODBC_SERVER123';
```

When I try to perform my select I receive the following error:

```
[SQL] select * from "legit_view"@ODBC_SERVER123
[Err] ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified {IM002}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from ODBC_SERVER123
```

I can successfully test ODBC locally on the SUSE/Postgres box with isql:

```
>isql -v postgresql ***** *****
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

What step have I forgotten?

Comment: Two things. 1. I think the driver should be "postgresql" in the odbc.ini (the title in odbcinst.ini) and 2. there is a command-line tool "isql" which can be used to test your unixodbc connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your odbc.ini file must be on the remote box!  That is, the one originating the query.  In the example above that would be the Oracle box.  Here is an entry that must go on the Oracle (remote) box:

```
[server123]
Driver = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Description = ODBC to PostgreSQL on Server 123
Trace = No
Tracefile = /var/log/sql_host_123.log
Servername = ip.address.for.123
Username = *****
Password = *****
Port = 5432
Protocol = 6.4
Database = host
QuotedId = Yes
ReadOnly            = No
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ShowOidColumn       = No
FakeOidIndex        = No
```